# How to implement interactive vertical Fragment transitions that follow swipe/touch?

Tags: android, interactive, fragmenttransaction, fragment-transitions

I'm trying to do a sort of infinite scroll. Each `Fragment` contains a scrolling `WebView` (or `ScrollView`), and when the user hits the bottom, I'd like to test for continued swiping to reveal the next `Fragment` below.

The user should not be able to go back, and I'm not interested in caching, so that rules out `RecyclerView` or `ViewPager` (modified to scroll vertically). I'm only concerned about managing the current `Fragment`, loading the next, and removing the last one once it's offscreen.

I want the next `Fragment` to follow the users touch, and I want the transition to abort if the user lets go below a certain threshold.

`FragmentManager` allows custom animations but they are non-interactive. I could perhaps write my own `ViewGroup` where I can manually animate a `Fragment` into position, and remove the previous `Fragment` manually, but I'm not sure if this is the best path forward.

Anyone have thoughts/tips on a good approach here?

Comment: If I were you I would not rule out using a modified `ViewPager` or `RecyclerView`. I would drop the fragment though, if it only encapsulates a `WebView`. You can probably just go along with a `RecyclerView` and block the scrolling back, by means of removing the child that is no longer shown to the user and adding the next one

Comment: "Cake" browser does something like this in a horizontal motion. Though they do have a back motion.